# perl / regex: how to find and replace between sets of every n characters

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have a very long code. I am joining lines by removing continuation characters using the normal regex

```
 s/<continuation chars>/\s/g
```

However this results in a line greater than the character limit of my compiler 17000 or the like.

How can i get this to be split between sections of 1699 characters:

I.e. find and replace ;
     if line length > limit ;
     skip next replace and begin process again

**
edit
**

I want to say: between newline characters, for every 1700 char (find and replace), find the next match and do not replace(ie skip), and then repeat for the next 1700..**

Comment: You can use `length` to check the length of a string. `\s` doesn't make sense in the replacement part of a substitution.

Comment: Would a space  suffice in replacing the newline (for the replacement part) instead?

Comment: TITS - "Try It To See"!

Comment: Fair, although the find and replace / \s works fine.  I'm guessing I would need to split the file string using the newlines to get a length count aswell.

Comment: In regex, to say `if line > limit`, you can use to limit value 1700: `^(?=.{1700,})something`... It means from start `^` lookahead `(?=)` to match from 1700 characters to more `.{1700,}` ... But in this case, I doubt regex is the right option

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way.

Comment: @Sobrique I want to say: between newline characters, for every 1700 (find and replace), find the next match and do not replace(ie skip), and then repeat for the next 1700...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `length` to get the length of a string. Just accumulate the total length in a variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $limit = 1700;

my $length = 0;
while (<>) {
    s/\n/ /;
    $length += length;
    if ($length > $limit + 1) {
        s/ $//;
        print "\n";
        $length = length;
    }
    print;
}
```